# Flutter autocomplete and even just running code doesn't work

Tags: flutter, dart, autocomplete

In my Flutter project autocomplete doesn't work.
[No intellisense](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81BI1.png)
[No AutoComplete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdc51.png)
[Even Basic Dart Code doesn't work(No Run text)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1ZfZ.png)

In my VSCode Developer Tools have an error
[VSCode Developer Tools Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJsWX.png)

[But Flutter Project Debugging is working correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PIEV.png)
[And there is no issue in flutter doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYwei.png)
My Flutter and Dart SDK version is (3.7.3/2.19.2)
[This is my Flutter and Dart SDK version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0d9dv.png)

I installed various flutter sdk and extension and checked the environment variable settings well, but none of them worked.

Comment: u may have ur ans here. [Same Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57000058/vs-code-and-flutter-dart-widget-autocomplete-not-working)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VS Code and Flutter/Dart, Widget Autocomplete not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57000058/vs-code-and-flutter-dart-widget-autocomplete-not-working)

Comment: Thank you guys. One of the solution of that post is available in my case.

Comment: Code completion in Dart/Flutter is powered by the Dart Analysis Server, a tool from the Dart SDK. I'd suggest reporting this issue to https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues