# Auto-complete not working in flutter(visual studio)

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I reopened a Flutter project in Visual Studio after a while, and I've noticed that the auto-complete feature is not working in my Dart files. Previously, I would receive suggestions for widgets such as StatefulWidget or StatelessWidget when typing abbreviations like stf. Additionally, when typing import m, the autocomplete would display the entire set of import files.
Could someone kindly provide guidance on how to resolve this issue?

I have installed the extensions like dart, flutter prior to running the app. I've tried running flutter update as well.
Flutter 3.16.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision b0366e0a3f (4 days ago) • 2023-12-05 19:46:39 -0800
Engine • revision 54a7145303
Tools • Dart 3.2.3 • DevTools 2.28.4

Answer (score 0):

- Try not to have extra Flutter extensions/plugins than needed.
- Reload packages from pubspec.yaml `flutter pub get`
- Disable Power Save mode from `File -> Power Save Mode`
- Restart your IDE

if non of these work try this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71889591/23074717)

### **update**

- Try restarting the Dart Analysis Server. Occasionally, this problem arises due to issues with the Dart Analysis Server. Restarting it often resolves the issue.

To restart the Dart Analysis Server:

1. Press `Ctrl + Shift + P`.
2. Search for a command called `Dart: Restart Analysis Server`.
3. Execute the command.

If restarting the Dart Analysis Server doesn't resolve the problem, consider restarting your IDE. This can sometimes clear up any lingering issues."

Comment: I've tried all of these steps, except for the power save mode one. However, I am unable to find that option. There is no such feature under the 'File' menu.

Comment: check my answer update